# ViewData of Actionfilter is not available in Base Controller property

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionfilterattribute

I have a basecontroller like this

```
  [Action]
  public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
  {
     public bool HasRight { get { return ((bool)ViewData["Actions2"]); } }        
  .........
  }
```

Action Attribute

```
public class ActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
      filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Actions2"]=true;
      .........
   }

}
```

When i call some view from certain controller I get null exception at

```
public bool HasRight { get { return ((bool)ViewData["Actions2"]); } } as ViewData is null
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [`OnActionExecuting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) which is executed before your Controller action and not [`OnActionExecuted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted.aspx).

This should work:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Actions2"]) = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `ViewData` from the `FilterContext` Like this:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Actions2"] = true;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

***Update :***

**After your update** i realized that you're trying to get access to `ViewData["Actions2"]` before setting the value to it.

So you should use `OnActionExecuting` instead of `OnActionExecuted` to ensure that the value has been set to the `ViewData`

Comment: Sorry that was typo I am getting viewdata from filtercontext